# Is there a way I could store id of my button used in a table?

Tags: php, forms

```
<?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
?>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <?php echo $row['Product_ID'] ?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $row['Product_Name'] ?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $row['Product_Price'] ?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $row['Product_Stock'] ?></td>
      <td> <button type="submit" name="add" id="<?php $row['Product_ID'] ?>" onclick="func(<?php $row['Product_ID'] ?>)"> Add </button></td>    
    </tr>

<?php } ?>`

<script type="text/javascript" method="post">
    function func(id){
        window.alert(id); 
    };
 </script>
```

Is there a way I could store id of my button named add?
I've to store multiple product ids and use them in a receipt that would be generated using product ids. the method of the form is `POST` but I don't know how to get the id

Comment: Why don't you just use a hidden field with name product id?

Comment: You are getting the product id in `fun()`. so what's the issue here?

Comment: I don't really know about hidden field, How would that help?

Comment: It says undefined when i used window.alert(id)

Comment: it's because `<?php $row['Product_ID'] ?>` needs to be `<?php echo $row['Product_ID']; ?>`. You forget `echo` there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
 func(<?php $row['Product_ID'] ?>)
```

With This

```
 func(<?php echo $row['Product_ID']; ?>)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!
Can I store multiple product ids every time I press the add button? like dynamically

Comment: Also, if you don't like the mixed languages (PHP+HTML+js), you can use the PHP short tag to output (*i.e. echo*) a variable `<?= $row['Product_ID'] ?>` (only with PHP 5.4+)

Comment: @OsamaZaman yes you can just change your `button`'s `name` value to `add[]`